# Expand Disk on VMware but no effect?

Tags: centos, vmware

I have a Virtual Host (CentOS 6.4) running on VMware. Hard disk of this PC is 100GB but I want to expand it to 500GB.

I tried to expand the Hard Disk (SCSI) to 500GB.

It's ok, no errors. But another PC (Windows 7) connected to this PC (CentOS 6.4) via samba, just shows "9GB free of 100GB". It means the PC (CentOS 6.4) has not expanded the disk.

I used an external HDD (500 GB) to run this PC (CentOS 6.4).

What did I do wrong?
Did I missed something?

Comment: You increased the disk size but you neither resized the partition nor allocated the added space to a new partition.

Comment: Could you please provide a `df -h`? In this way we can help understanding what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if vmware will edit the partition table for you, but You need to also expand the file system. if you are using ext2/3/4 the tool to do this is resise2fs. read its man page for details. Some other file systems have similar tools. those that do not will need a reformat.

Comment: He will need to resize the partition in addition to the filesystem, or if he is using LVM, add another partition to the VG and extend.

Comment: I would be careful with any resizing one attempts to do on a filesystem. If you don't know what you're doing you can wreck your data. I would suggest setting a sacrificial instance up identical to the real one and do a dry run with it 1st.

Comment: Thank you, but i can't format my data... So sorry. I found that my SDA: 483gb, SDA1: 300GB, SDA2: 105gb. So i think that SDA and SDA1 have not mounted to SDA2. Could you please help me how to mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a howto tutorial on adding hard disk to centos6. Click [here](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=add_hd)

Also you have to `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb` or `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb` to format to ext3 or ext4 file system. Then you have to mount that partition, `mount /dev/sdb /tmp/test`.

Now you have to share this `/tmp/test` folder in samba server so that you can use that 500gigs HD from a remote system.

Answer (score 0):

Just increasing the virtual 'physical' disk size does not magically enlarge the size of the mounted partition.

If you check with `fdisk -l /dev/diskname` (probably `sdb` but make sure you have the right one first) you'll see a 100G partition `/dev/diskname1` and 400 gigabyte unallocated.

The smoothest way to do this, especially if you're unfamiliar with the various ins and outs, is using `gparted` on a live image -- go [here](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and download the iso into the vmware datastore, then tell vmware to mount the image and boot into BIOS setup on next launch.

Reboot, then in the virtual BIOS change boot order to try the CD first so it'll launch the `gparted` ISO. Follow the instructions to resize your drive, then once you've shut down unmount the ISO in vmware and restart.

This method has worked flawlessly for me with every system I've used it on so far.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
But is there any tutorial how to mount sda and sda1 to sda2? Please help me.